# Rotating Image around y axis

Tags: css

I have an image which is divided into two equal parts. I am trying rotate the right part of the image in -180°(anti-clockwise) around y axis on hover.

Problem is some times(randomly) image gets rotated in 180°(clockwise) instead of -180°(anti-clockwise). what might be the reason behind this? I am using chrome.

css:-

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top : 10px;
  width : 500px;
  height: 330px;
   -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 13px #AAA;
}

.frontDiv {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 330px;  
}

.frontImg {
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid;
  height : 281px;
  width : 225px;  
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('iday.jpg');
  transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility : hidden;
   -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%; 
}

.f1 {
  top: 20px;
  left:20px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}


.f2 {
  top: 20px;
  left:245px;
  background-position: -225px 0px;
}

.frontDiv:hover .f2
{ 
 -webkit-transform : rotateY(-180deg);
 }
```

html:-

```
<article class='container'>
  <div class='frontDiv'>
    <div class='frontImg f1'></div>
    <div class='frontImg f2'></div>
  </div>
</article>
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/WxFpp/)

Comment: I have been unable to see the error happening. Anyway, I have added a fiddle with your code; this way it's easier to test.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error either from the fiddle.

Comment: @vals thanks for the fiddle vals, for me in your fiddle div is rotating in clockwise direction, all the time. even at -180 degree angle

Comment: The fiddle is a copy-paste of the code that you provided. Probably the problem is somewhere else in your real page. I mean about the transform doing randomly different things. It's not clear for me from your comment if you are expecting the rotation to go the opposite way.  About that, I would say that the behaviour is ok; but I am not absolutely sure, this kind of things are easy to missunderstand (at least for me)

Comment: The fiddle sometimes doesn't do the 3D depth effect. That is, it does [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5DDnI.png) instead of [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qg6R.png). And yes, it seems random.

Comment: @MrLister Really unable to see it ...  Chrome  28.0.1500.95 m on Windows.

Comment: @vals Maybe it's a bug in later versions. I'll have to check.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe No, sorry, other than "probably a bug", I can't say anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the browsers are not supported rotate like,
Internet Explorer 9 (and earlier versions) and Opera does not support the rotateX or rotateY method.

else try

```
.frontDiv:hover .f2
{ 
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
 }
```

Comment: I've tried this in your code..and its working with my firefox 23.0.1

Comment: I am using chrome, and i have used -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg); in my code

Comment: @shivoham while true, and relevant, your answer doesn't address the OP's question, why the hover transition doesn't always behave the same, even on the same Chrome browser, on subsequent mouse-overs, without doing anything in between.

Comment: @Mr. Lister not agreed with you for same browser and same version effect works same.I have tried it in chrome 28.that 3D effect is superb one though differ than mozilla..Ya may in chrome 27 it will be different...